# VSCode - Changing colours inside IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, colors, visual-studio-code

I changed different color settings inside my VSCode based on
[VSCode Theme Color](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#dropdown-control)

But I couldn't find any settings to change the colors inside VSCode Intellisense.

Looking at the screenshot bellow, VSCode is suggesting "script" or "script:src".
How can I change the backgroundColor of the active line inside the Intellisense?

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Ok, after a bit more search I found the answer myself.

This is what you need to add to your user settings:

```
"editorSuggestWidget.background": "<your color>",
"editorSuggestWidget.selectedBackground": "<your color>"
```

I used only the second line to give the selected suggestion a bolder colour.

[image]

Comment: For clarity these go under "workbench.colorCustomizations": {}. Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Comment: Here is a whole snippet with a half decent color for people in the future if you just want to copy/paste: 
```"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorSuggestWidget.selectedBackground": "#424d66",
  }```